# How to create a table in Snowflake with First row as null?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am creating a snowflake table with a query with is a composite of other queries,

```
CREATE or Replace TABLE dbname.dummy.xyz_abc as 
( 
select * from a 
join b on a.id=b.id
)
```

I want the first row to be all nulls.

Comment: Which column or columns define what is the "first" row?  Can you add sample data showing what the final table should look like?

Comment: There is no "first" row in a table.  What are you trying to actually do?

Comment: @Andrew I am trying to create a first row null so that I can create a waterfall chart in tableau, strange but apparently that's how it works

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen so basically lets say I have 10 columns, so the first row will contain 10 value that says 'null'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `union`?

```sql
CREATE or Replace TABLE dbname.dummy.xyz_abc as 
(
select null, null, null, ... -- "null" times number of columns
union all
select * from a 
join b on a.id=b.id
)
```

Comment: you might want a UNION ALL, on the basis that there currently is no all nulls row. And therefore adding one, does not need duplicating. Or if the "duplicating aspect of the UNION was intented, you might want to mention this.